# How can I print the cookie_jar values in Perl's WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, cookies

How can I print the values of the cookie/cookie_jar being set?

Trying:

```
##my $cookie_jar=HTTP::Cookies->new(file => "cookie.jar",autosave=>1,ignore_discard=>1);
my $cookie_jar=HTTP::Cookies->new(); ## Would like it to be in memory
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new(cookie_jar => $cookie_jar);

##my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new();
##my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1);

##$agent->cookie_jar( {} );

# we need cookies
##$agent->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new);

print "Set Cookie Jar?\n";
print $agent->cookie_jar->as_string();
print "\n";

$agent->get($url); // url is a https site
```

Not too much luck with any of these, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You define a Monster agent which will print the values of the cookies as they come out of the jar. You can have 3 levels of detail.. "-NOM", "-NOMNOM", and "-NOMNOMNOM".

Comment: so my $monster->eat(cookie_jar->cookie);, LOL

Comment: correct. note that this is a destructive operation though and you won't get cookies back.

Comment: Please make a complete and minimal working program. Where is, for instance, `$url` set? You'll get much better answers when you take the time to make a good question. You might even answer your own question that way. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you have to have some cookies in the cookie jar to see any cookies in the output. So far you have an empty cookie jar. Either ensure that you add some cookies or that the site you are accessing sets them:

```
use HTTP::Cookies;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new;
my $agent      = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => $cookie_jar );

$cookie_jar->set_cookie(
    qw(
    3
    cat
    buster
    /
    .example.com
    0
    0
    0
    )
    );

    $agent->get( 'http://www.amazon.com' );

print "Set Cookie Jar?\n", $agent->cookie_jar->as_string, "\n";
```

This gave me the output:

```
Set Cookie Jar?
Set-Cookie3: session-id=000-0000000-0000000; path="/"; domain=.amazon.com; path_spec; discard; version=0
Set-Cookie3: session-id-time=1272524400l; path="/"; domain=.amazon.com; path_spec; discard; version=0    Set-Cookie3: cat=buster; path="/"; domain=.example.com; port=0; version=3
```

However, you don't need to invoke `HTTP::Cookies` directly. `LWP` will take care of that. You just give `cookie_jar` a hash reference:

```
    my $agent      = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => {} );
```

If you just want the cookies from a particular response, you can create a separate cookie jar to hold the ones you extract from the response:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => {} );

my $response = $agent->get( 'http://www.amazon.com' );

my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new;
$cookie_jar->extract_cookies( $response );

print $cookie_jar->as_string;
```

Comment: sry, new to this screen-scraping stuff. I have $agent->get($url); does this add the cookie to the cookie jar. Sorry I need to laugh after I typed that, LMAO!!!

Comment: Always show a complete working example so you don't waste anyone's time fixing the errors you don't actually have. :) You can edit your question to fix that, too. :)

Comment: hmm maybe I'm not asking the question right. How do I print the cookie that the site I'm crawling is sending/setting?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a value of a specific cookie, you will need to scan the whole cookie jar using [HTTP::Cookie's $cookie_jar->scan( \&callback )](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Cookies-6.01/lib/HTTP/Cookies.pm#%24cookie_jar-%3Escan%28_%5C&callback_%29) method. For example, to get JSESSIONID cookie from www.linkedin.com, you can use the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies::Netscape;

my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies::Netscape->new(
    hide_cookie2 => 1, 
    file => "$ENV{HOME}/.cookies.txt",
    autosave => 1
    );

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    env_proxy => 1,
    autocheck => 1,
    cookie_jar => $cookies,
    agent => "get-jsessionid.pl/1.0"
    );

$browser->env_proxy();

my $response = $browser->get( 'http://www.linkedin.com' );
if ($response->is_success)
{
    $cookies->scan(sub 
                   {
                       if ($_[1] eq 'JSESSIONID')
                       {
                           print "$_[1] @ $_[4] = $_[2]\n";
                       };
                   }
        );
}
else
{
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

The output would be something like:

> JSESSIONID @ www.linkedin.com = "ajax:11122233344455556667"

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem seems to be that you are trying to print the cookies before you actually visit the site. Try moving your print statements after your call to `get()`